# Получить список всех ссылок, которые не находятся внутри списка <ul>

Tags: javascript, dom

Помогите, пожалуйста, с задачей.
Нужно с помощью свойств DOM, получить список всех ссылок, которые не находятся внутри списка . У меня такой вот код, он правильный?

```js
let links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('body a')).filter(link => !link.closest('ul'));
console.log(links);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <article>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio omnesque ius cu, quo ex atqui antiopam. At detracto menandri eos. Duo in causae viderer, graeci <a href="#">reprehendunt</a> has in. Decore <mark>nemore</mark> philosophia te pro, nobis legere causae ex mei, odio putant mentitum ea ius. Vix nostro deserunt explicari eu.</p>
    </article>
</div>
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul><span></span>
<a href="#">Some link</a>
 
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, вы все верно сделали.

Comment: Можно сделать еще так let links = $('a:not(#list a)');

Comment: `Нужно с помощью свойств DOM, получить список всех ссылок, которые не находятся внутри списка` `document.querySelectorAll(':not(li) > a')` как то так вроде

Answer (score 0):

```
let link = document.querySelectorAll('body a');

console.log([...link].filter(link => !link.closest('ul')));
```